# How to delete the effect particle when summoning a mob

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can we delete the effect particle  when summoning a mob?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a mod to remove the effect? Or how to disable it from the vanilla game?

Comment: @pushasha The minecraft-commands tag suggests the OP wants to disable it from the vanilla game. However, this question should be developed a bit more to enable a prompt answer.

Comment: Do you want to remve the particle effect *entirely*, or *only* when you're summoning mobs?

Comment: What I mean is when summoning the mob, thank you for the remarks guys I will edit my question a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

The `ShowParticles` tag, when set to 0, will hide particles from that effect. The datatype of 'byte' must be declared by appending the numerical value with a "b":

```
/summon Creeper ~ ~1 ~ {ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Duration:1000000,ShowParticles:0b}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't going to give the mob a name you can do this:

```
/summon Cow ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"noeffect"}
```

Then:

```
/scoreboard objectives add noeffect dummy
```

Then:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Cow] noeffect 1 {CustomName:"noeffect"}
```

Then:

```
/effect @e[score_noeffect_min=1] EFFECT SECONDS AMPLIFIER true
```

True makes deletes the particles.

*Sure there is another way, but this works!*

**//dnorhoj**